# Overload extension methods of T

Tags: xml, vb.net, reflection, types, extension-methods

I want to create a XML document by the properties of an instance. For that I write two extensions.

```vb
<Extension()>
Public Function ToXml(Of T)(ByVal source As T) As XmlDocument
    Dim oXmlDocument As New XmlDocument
    oXmlDocument.AppendChild(oXmlDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", Nothing))
    oXmlDocument.AppendChild(oXmlDocument.CreateElement(XmlConvert.EncodeName(source.GetType.ToString)))

    For Each Item As System.Reflection.FieldInfo In source.GetType.GetFields
        Dim oElement As XmlElement = oXmlDocument.CreateElement(Item.Name)
        oElement.Attributes.Append(oXmlDocument.CreateAttribute("Value")).Value = Item.GetValue(Nothing).ToString
        oXmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(oElement)
    Next

    Return oXmlDocument
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function ToXml(Of T)(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of T)) As XmlDocument
    Dim oXmlDocument As New XmlDocument
    oXmlDocument.AppendChild(oXmlDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", Nothing))
    oXmlDocument.AppendChild(oXmlDocument.CreateElement(XmlConvert.EncodeName(source.GetType.ToString)))

    For Each Item As T In source
        oXmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(oXmlDocument.ImportNode(Item.ToXml.DocumentElement, True))
    Next

    Return oXmlDocument
End Function
```

The second method should be for types by `IEnumerable(Of T)` and the first for all others. If I try it for an instance of `Button`, `String`, `Int32` or something like this it works fine. With an instance of i.e. `List(Of T)` also the first method will be called. It seems that the extension for `IEnumerable(Of T)` is ignored because the range  is wider for the extension of T.

Is there a possibility to force a `List(Of T)` to use the extension for `IEnumerable(Of T)`?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [overload "signature"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3tbathb.aspx) does not include Generic Constraints, so adjusting the `Of T` with an `As` clause doesn't seem to help.

For simple (non-generic) interfaces the same "problem" occurs, in that the closest match to a class is chosen for the overload to use.

So noting that for some class, `List(Of Integer)` say, the two signatures are `ToXml(List(Of Integer))` and `ToXml(IEnumerable(Of Integer))` thus it will clearly choose the former, being an exact match.

Because of the "Not most specific." error, I don't even have a solution that allows you to give future coders a hint they've called the wrong routine. The best I can suggest is to not use overloads for objects that can be lists :-(

I.e. have `ToXmlFromObject(Of T)(ByVal source As T)` and `ToXmlFromList(Of T)(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of T))`

And, at runtime ( :-( ), you can use reflection in `ToXmlFromObject` to check for usage by Enumerables. Something like this (entered directly into the SO textbox):

```
Debug.Assert(GetType(T) Is GetType(String) _
    OrElse Not (From i In GetType(T).GetInterfaces() _
        Where i Is GetType(IEnumerable)).Any)
```

---

I should also mention the other option hinted at by some error messages: You can continue to overload both `ToXml(As T)` and `ToXml(As IEnumerable(Of T))`, but don't rely on implied overloads. I.e. explicitly list the `(Of ElementType)` to ensure the `ToXml(Of ElementType)(As IEnumerable(Of ElementType))` version is called. (This would still fail when you do have `SomeType` implementing `IEnumerable(Of SomeType)`.)

---

#### Wrong answer

*As I mentioned in comments, this fails because you'd want to specify a different type that `T` in the `IEnumerable(Of )` cast.*

*Also I now notice this would fail because calling `ToXml` with `IEnumerable(Of Anything)` would error because both signatures described above would be the same, so it errors with "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ToXml' is most specific for these arguments: ... Not most specific. ... Not most specific.".*

I think your only option is to manually "force" the overloading in the other direction; i.e. in the exact case, check if the interface matches, and call that overload:

```vb
<Extension()>
Public Function ToXml(Of T)(ByVal source As T) As XmlDocument
  Dim enumSource = TryCast(source, IEnumerable(Of T))
  If enumSource IsNot Nothing Then Return ToXml(enumSource)
  ...
```